# Find the minimum number of moves for Sum(A) <= B

Tags: python, algorithm

You are given two non-negative integers A and B. Let the function Sum(A) be the sum of digits of the number A.
You can perform any number of moves (possibly zeros).

- In one move you can increase the value of A by 1.

Find the minimum number of moves you have to perform to make `sum(A) <= B`.

Constraints:

```
1 <= A <= 10^12

1 <= B <= 108
```

Sample Test Cases:

```
1. A = 1, B = 1       Output = 0
2. A = 9, B = 2       Output = 1
3. A = 555, B = 10    Output = 45
```

- Inputs are given in string.

How to solve this problem in python?

Here is the code I have tried:

```
def countmoves(A, B):

    int_A = int(A)
    int_B = int(B)
    count = 0
    
    while True:
        digits = [int(i) for i in str(int_A)]
        s_m = sum(digits)
        if s_m <= int_B:
            print(f"count: {count}")
            return count
        else:
            int_A += 1
            count += 1
```

But my code is getting Timed Out. How can I optimize it?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: Start by doing a few examples on paper by hand.

Comment: I have added the solution to the problem I have tried, but not able to optimize it.

Comment: Your algorithm is brute force. It will work with small numbers but will fail when the input is larger. You will need to think of an algorithm that does not repeatedly increase int_a by 1.

Comment: Think about this: When you increase A by 1, how does the sum of its digits change?

Comment: This post has a pretty high view count…. Are many people trying to solve this at the same time? Programming competition question?

Comment: I am trying implement the logic as follows: 

suppose the number is 783910
look at the very end 783910
you can't decrease this, so look at 2 digits 783910
you can drop this to 0, make a 90 step and you get 784000, now start over
What should be the logic to write this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by finding the rightmost non-zero number and adding a value such that the element to the left is increased by `1` and all to the right (inclusive) become `0`:

```
def countmoves(A, B): #nin17()
    count = 0
    B = int(B)
    while True:
        total = sum(int(i) for i in A)
        if total <= B:
            return count
        else:
            index = max(A.rfind(i) for i in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'])
            right = A[index:]
            moves = 10**len(right)-int(right)
            A = f'{int(A)+moves}'
            count += moves
```

Or with a for loop instead, looping from right to left through `A`:

```
def countmoves(A, B): #nin172()
    count = 0
    B = int(B)
    for i, j in enumerate(range(len(A)-1, -2, -1), 1):
        total = sum(int(i) for i in A)
        if total <= B:
            return count
        else:
            moves = 10**i-int(A[j:])
            A = f'{int(A)+moves}'
            count += moves
```

Timings (with given test cases):

```
for A, B in (('1', '1'), ('9', '2'), ('555', '10')):
    %timeit op(A, B)
    %timeit nin17(A, B) #while
    %timeit nin172(A, B) #for
```

Output:

```
600 ns ± 9.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) #OP
473 ns ± 2.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) #Nin17 while
732 ns ± 1.94 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) #Nin17 for
1.12 µs ± 8.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) #OP
2.6 µs ± 44.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each) #Nin17 while
1.58 µs ± 2.49 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each) #Nin17 for
26.6 µs ± 63.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each) #OP
5.18 µs ± 7.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each) #Nin17 while
2.89 µs ± 17.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each) #Nin17 for
```

Timings with larger values:

```
A = '363513974325'
B = '28'
assert op(A, B) == nin17(A, B)
assert nin17(A, B) == nin172(A, B)
%timeit op(A, B)
%timeit nin17(A, B)
%timeit nin172(A, B)
```

Output:

```
45.2 ms ± 66.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) #OP
19.3 µs ± 197 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each) #Nin17 while
12.2 µs ± 18.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each) #Nin17 for
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def digit_sum(A):
    return sum(list(map(int, str(A).strip())))

def countmoves(A, B):
    final_moves = 0
    place_holder = 0

    while digit_sum(A) > B:
        place_holder += 1
        remainder = A % (10 ** place_holder)
        if (remainder):
            moves = (10 ** place_holder) - remainder
            A = A + moves
            final_moves += moves

    return(final_moves)
```